# Abstraction and Pure virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to implement some derived classes that inherit part of their behaviour from the base class.
The base class is something like this:

```
class Number {
 public:
  virtual string getName() = 0;
  void writeName() {
   string name = this->getName();
   printf("My Name is %s\n", name.c_str());
  }

  Number() {
   this->writeName();
  }
};

class One : Number {
 string getName() {return string("One");}
};

class Two : Number {
 string getName() {return string("Two");}
};

int main() {
 One *n = new One();
}
```

I would expect this to output "My Name is One", but I get an exception saying 'pure virtual method called'. Am I approaching this the wrong way? Or am I missing something in the declaration of the classes and members, and so I am achieving this unexcpted result? Or is this actually the expected result, and if so, how can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Give all of the clases virtual destructors.

Comment: You don't need the `string` bit around the `"One"`. Although it's only a simple example, you don't need `new` in your main function. Your `printf` function is wrong. C strings and std::strings don't concatenate in that way. Try `cout` which is easier.

Comment: Read https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors and the following answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk I corrected the printf error, I wrote the example out of my head and wrote that bit wrong. Although, neither of those are related with the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this exception because you are calling the method from inside the constructor. According to C++ rules, all virtual member functions inside a class constructor are dispatched to implementations inside the class itself, not its subclass. The logic behind this decision is that otherwise a member function would run on an object before its initialization has been completed.

There is no workaround to this: if you need constructors of subclasses to perform different actions, the code performing these actions should be placed inside subclass constructors themselves.

Comment: Thank you. removing the call to writeName() from the constructor to main resolved the issue. It seems cleaner to have it inside the constructor, but it works like a charm :)